# Understanding a theorem about analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f(z)$ is analytic in the region $\Omega'$  and is obtained by omitting a point $b$ from a region $\Omega$. A necessary and sufiecient condition that there exists an analytic function in $\Omega$ which coincides w/ $f(z)$ in $\Omega'$ is $$\lim_{z \to b} (z-b)f(z) = 0$$

Can someone help me understand what is going with the above theorem?

So we have a function $f(z)$ which is analytic of a region that has a point missing. An "extended" function $f'(z)$ is analytic function in $\Omega$ (the region that includes the point) must satisfy the condition $\lim_{z \to b}(z-b)f(z) = 0$. Why?

Comment: If $f$ is the restriction of an analytic function $\tilde f$ in $\Omega$ then the limit is simply $(b - b)\tilde f(b) = 0$ because $\tilde f$ is continuous. The reverse direction is not trivial, but covered in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity. – (Denoting the extension by $f'$ is perhaps not a good idea because that is the derivative of $f$.)

Comment: Look at the chapter "Classification of isolated singularities" in your textbook.